# Dynamically adding a picture based on id tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have pictures in row like so

[image]

and they have corresponding id tags. When you click on one of them they bring up a popup:

[image]

which is loaded by this javascript:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() 
{
    $('div.recentbox').click(function()
    {
        var name = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#titlethumb').prepend('<img class="imgs" src="stuff/"+name+"/thumbnail.jpg" />');
        $('.box-inner').fadeOut('fast',function()
        {
            $('.box-inner').load('stuff/'+name+'/description.html', function()
            {
                $('.box-inner').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

description.html

```
<div id="infobox-wrap">
    <div id="infobox">
        <div id="titlethumb">
            <h2 class="infobox">linkur.com</h2>
            <img id="imgs" src=""> <!--this image should be found in stuff/linkur/thumbnail.jpg-->
        </div>

        <div id="descriptionbuttons">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ut leo quis ante sagittis volutpat ut quis dolor. Vivamus ut leo ut erat pellentesque imperdiet nec eget turpis. Nunc sit amet elit dictum nulla tristique venenatis ut sed purus. Nulla facilisi. Duis ac dictum lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam scelerisque eros ac lacus cursus pulvinar. Praesent lobortis ipsum sit amet tellus fringilla vel lacinia diam auctor. Aliquam vel mattis odio. Sed tincidunt turpis in neque ullamcorper euismod. Nulla sed ante erat. Duis cursus massa facilisis neque eleifend sed viverra mi pulvinar. Morbi ultricies cursus libero sed ultrices. Donec non magna nibh. Phasellus tempor massa diam, tincidunt cursus justo. Vestibulum bibendum nisi in odio tincidunt vel dignissim leo vestibulum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Vivamus non nisi id ante congue suscipit ut ut urna. Morbi non sapien nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse potenti. Sed at mauris ut turpis bibendum fringilla. Nam nec urna quis mauris porta venenatis. Sed tempus tortor vitae mauris viverra id mattis lectus aliquet.
            </p>

            <div id="overlaybuttons">
                <a href="#"><span class="orangebtn" id="ourworkbtn">Button</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span class="orangebtn" id="ourworkbtn">Button</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.php

```
<body>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-inner">
        </div>

    </div>
```

but unfortunately the picture doesn't load.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 5):

You need to close the single quotes, not the double quotes:

```
var name = this.id;

$('#titlethumb').prepend('<img class="imgs" src="stuff/' + name + '/thumbnail.jpg" />');
```

Or more cleanly:

```
$('<img>', {
    'class': 'imgs',
    'src': 'stuff/' + name + '/thumbnail.jpg'
}).prependTo('#titlethumb');
```

Comment: get firebug or use chrome debugger...these are standard tools that will help you see everything from syntax errors to incorrect urls.

Comment: @tsand: That's not really helpful. What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Timmerz No errors, but the picture I'm trying to load the div is in "description.html" which is a different file. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @Blender I don't get any errors, the picture doesn't load. I inspected it too, the url doesn't seem to be inserted.

Comment: @tsand you should post both html and your script...we can't really see the full picture...

Comment: I don't see any `div.recentbox` in your code which means the click would never fire. are you not posting the full source?

Comment: oh that's later in the code. It does fire, but the image never shows.